# How to combine same css styling for different browsers

Tags: html, css

I'm using [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to change the styling of some elements.

For some stylings there are different versions for different browsers. In this case, `fit-content` for Chrome and `-moz-fit-content` for Mozilla.

If I want to run on Chrome the code looks like:

```
document.querySelector('.my-element').style.height = "fit-content";
```

For Mozilla:

```
document.querySelector('.my-element').style.height = "-moz-fit-content";
```

My question is: is there a way to combine them? With the above way of work it goes well only for one browser at a time, I would like to work well for both.

Answer (score 3):

Browser detection/sniffing should be avoided given the large, unpredictable (and changeable) range of possible answers.

Define classes in your CSS that include the prefixes you need and add (or replace) the class to the element [MDN: className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className). The JavaScript would be a single statement, adding a class that already lists all the vendor prefixes.

```
.anotherclass {
    height: -moz-fit-content;
    height: -webkit-fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
}

document.querySelector('.my-element').className = 'anotherclass';
```

If you wanted to you could also use a tool like [PrefixR](http://prefixr.com/index.php), or similar, to add prefixes to your stylesheets.

Also worth pointing out is [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/) to check whether you still need some prefixes.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work for me. it ignores the height for both browsers, I also tried like:     `height: fit-content;
    -moz-height: fit-content;
    -webkit-height: fit-content;`, same result

Comment: That is a different question. You asked how to combine various prefixed values. Maybe there is some error with your code, or perhaps the height of an already rendered element won't adjust with the application of `fit-content`. You might create a new question for this.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible if you can use [navigator.appCodeName](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_navigator.asp) to select which `style.height` you want to have.

For example:

```
if(navigator.appCodeName == "Mozilla"){
    document.querySelector('.my-element').style.height = "-moz-fit-content";
}else{
    document.querySelector('.my-element').style.height = "fit-content";
}
```

"Mozilla" is the application code name for both Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari, and Opera.

Answer (score -2):

may be this will help, you can detect browser like below

```
window.browser = (function () {
    return window.msBrowser ||
        window.browser ||
        window.chrome;
})();
console.log(window.browser);
```